# Add close bracket ")" to end of regex lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
word1
wrd(456
trhyjh
ABCD (ytyh
word2((tyhju
```

I can select my intended lines by `^(.*?\().*$` regex.
Now I want to add close bracket `)` to end of my intended lines that can select by regex.
How to do this?

Comment: Just put your regex in a capture group `^(.*?\(.*)$` and replace with `\1\)`

Comment: @Nick I get this answer from chatGPT too but I tried it multiple times and not worked for me!

Comment: See my edited comment. It's a weird notebook++ replacement thing, you need to escape the `)`

Comment: @Nick yes it worked for me. please send as answer then I will accept your answer.

Comment: It's fine, I suspect this is a duplicate anyway. Have a great day.

Comment: @Nick yes maybe my question is dublicate

Comment: @PubgMobile Your regex will also add a close `)` if there is already one. To avoid this you can use exclusion: [`\([^)\n]*$\K`](https://regex101.com/r/O3u2oM/2)